# bdo, bdi, or span/p/div with dir attribute?

Tags: html, language

I don't get the difference between these options. What is the difference between them & which one is better for SEO or rendering?

Comment: http://rishida.net/blog/?p=564

Answer (score 1):

Given that the [bdi tag is not supported](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdi.asp) by Internet Explorer, Safari, or Opera; you can't use that tag on sites that will be viewed cross-browser.

The [bdo tag has better browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdo.asp) and it could be used.

Google and other search engines don't usually pay too much attention to which tags your use.   Use the tags that work in all the browsers and look right to your users.   Which ones you choose won't matter to search engines.

Comment: But what difference would it make to use the bdo tag instead of the dir attribute?